# How To Clear MemoryBuffer of UPLOAD component

Tags: upload, components, vaadin

First Timer here: I have an upload component which takes a image and displaying it in a layout. A save button triggers Saving the image to DB and works fine.

Here's the problem: for the next record, On trrigering save method, if no image is added to the upload component, the previous image is saved again.(I guess memorybuffer still has that image). So my question is, how do i clear the memory buffer for the next record. Also, i would like to know if i can retrieve the image displayed in the imagecontainer to save it to an Image variable.

````
```

    public class EmployeeForm extends FormLayout {
        
        Image image;
        Button save = new Button("Save");
        Button delete = new Button("Delete");
        Button close = new Button("Close");
        MemoryBuffer buffer= new MemoryBuffer();
        Upload upload= new Upload(buffer); 
        VerticalLayout imageContainer=new VerticalLayout();
        BufferedImage inputImageoriginal=null;
        public EmployeeForm(List<Office> offices, List<Cell> cells, DbService dbservice) {
            binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
            office.setItems(dbservice.findOfficesBydistrict());
            cell.setItems(dbservice.findCellsBydistrict());
            office.setItemLabelGenerator(Office::getOfficeName);
            cell.setItemLabelGenerator(Cell::getCellName);
            add(firstName, lastName, designation, office, cell, createUpload(), createButtonsLayout(), imageContainer);
        }
    
        private Component createUpload() {
            upload.setMaxFiles(1);
            upload.setMaxFileSize(100000);
            upload.setUploadButton(new Button ("Upload Photo"));
            upload.setDropLabel(new Label("Drop Photo"));
            upload.setAcceptedFileTypes("image/tiff", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg");
            upload.addFileRejectedListener(e -> notify.show("Invalid File: Please select only image files less than 100kb",3000, Position.TOP_END));
            upload.addSucceededListener(event -> showPicture());
            return upload;
        }
    
        public void showPicture() {
            try {
                if (imageContainer != null) {
                    remove(imageContainer);
                }
                StreamResource resource = new StreamResource("inputimage",
                        () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(getImageAsByteArray()));
                image = new Image(resource, "No Photo to display");
                imageContainer = new VerticalLayout();
                imageContainer.setWidth("200px");
                imageContainer.setHeight("200px");
                imageContainer.getStyle().set("overflow-x", "auto");
                imageContainer.add(image);
                add(imageContainer);
                //imageContainer.get
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                notify.show("Error" + e);
            }
        }
        
        public void clearBuffer() {
            try {
                upload.clearFileList();
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    
        private byte[] getImageAsByteArray() {
            try {
                
                inputImageoriginal= ImageIO.read(buffer.getInputStream());
                if (inputImageoriginal == null) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    BufferedImage inputImage = resizeImage(inputImageoriginal);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream pngContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIO.write(inputImage, "jpg", pngContent);
                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pngContent.toByteArray());
                    return IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        
        
        BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage) throws IOException {
            BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(150, 150, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D graphics2D = resizedImage.createGraphics();
            graphics2D.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, 150, 150, null);
            graphics2D.dispose();
            return resizedImage;
        }
    
        private Component createButtonsLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            save.setWidthFull();
            delete.setWidthFull();
            close.setWidthFull();
            save.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
            save.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
            save.addClickListener(event -> validatandSave());
            delete.addClickListener(event -> fireEvent(new DeleteEvent(this, employee)));
            close.addClickListener(event -> fireEvent(new CloseEvent(this)));
            return new HorizontalLayout(save, delete, close);
        }
    
        private void validatandSave() {
            try {
                
                binder.writeBean(employee);
                if (getImageAsByteArray() != null) {
                    employee.setPicture(getImageAsByteArray());
                }
    
                fireEvent(new SaveEvent(this, employee));
                
            } catch (ValidationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Notification notification = Notification.show("Please Enter All Required Fields", 3000,
                        Position.TOP_CENTER);
            }
        }
    
        public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
            this.employee = employee;
            binder.readBean(employee);
        }
    
    ///Operation Save/Delete Events
    
        public static abstract class EmployeeFormEvent extends ComponentEvent<EmployeeForm> {
            private Employee employee;
    
            protected EmployeeFormEvent(EmployeeForm source, Employee employee) {
                super(source, false);
                this.employee = employee;
            }
    
            public Employee getEmployee() {
                return employee;
            }
        }
    
        public static class SaveEvent extends EmployeeFormEvent {
            SaveEvent(EmployeeForm source, Employee employee) {
                super(source, employee);
            }
        }
    
        public static class DeleteEvent extends EmployeeFormEvent {
            DeleteEvent(EmployeeForm source, Employee employee) {
                super(source, employee);
            }
    
        }
    
        public static class CloseEvent extends EmployeeFormEvent {
            CloseEvent(EmployeeForm source) {
                super(source, null);
            }
        }
    
        public <T extends ComponentEvent<?>> Registration addListener(Class<T> eventType,
                ComponentEventListener<T> listener) {
            return getEventBus().addListener(eventType, listener);
        }
    
    
        public void addImage(Image image2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // remove(imageContainer);
            if(imageContainer!=null) {
                imageContainer.removeAll();
            }
            imageContainer.add(image2);
            //add(imageContainer);
        
        }
    }

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of `MemoryBuffer`, you have to throw it away and set a new one, e.g. in your `clearBuffer()` method.

```
buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
upload.setReceiver(buffer);
```

Comment: Thank You so much. Works like a charm. I was using upload=new Upload(buffer); Exception thrown : buffer is null.